# Flutter DataTable - how to make a table with varying number of datacell (make some datacell span multiple columns)

Tags: flutter

I intend to output a table with 2 rows, the first row contains 3 columns, the second one contains just one, meaning the cell in the second row should span 3 columns.

Here's my code:

```
 DataTable(
      columns: [
        DataColumn(label: Text('#')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Price')),
      ],
      rows: [
        DataRow(cells: [
          DataCell(Text('1')),
          DataCell(Text(orderItem.title)),
          DataCell(Text(orderItem.price.toString())),
        ]),
        DataRow(cells: [
          DataCell('Total: ${orderItem.price}'),
        ]),
      ],
)
```

Since the second row has only 1 datacell, this is the error that I'm getting:

```
'package:flutter/src/material/data_table.dart': Failed assertion: line 480 pos 15: '!rows.any((DataRow row) => row.cells.length != columns.length)': is not true.
```

How do I make the second row cell span 3 columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, there is no support for spanning. I usually either add empty cells (if you don't need the space) or, if you really do need to span multiple cells with your content, single column tables (or just a `Column`) with `Row` widgets in the cells.

```
 DataTable(
      columns: [
        DataColumn(label: Text('#')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
        DataColumn(label: Text('Price')),
      ],
      rows: [
        DataRow(cells: [
          DataCell(Text('1')),
          DataCell(Text(orderItem.title)),
          DataCell(Text(orderItem.price.toString())),
        ]),
        DataRow(cells: [
          DataCell(Text('Total: ${orderItem.price}')),
          DataCell(SizedBox.shrink()),
          DataCell(SizedBox.shrink()),
        ]),
      ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you notice or not, but the no of columns in your code is 3 while no of cells is 1. You can see
If it is empty, you can send that column empty.
so you need to create 3 columns of any kind.

```
  DataTable(
    columns: [
       DataColumn(label: Text('#')),
      DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
      DataColumn(label: Text('Price')),
    ],
    rows: [
      DataRow(cells: [
        DataCell(Text('1')),
        DataCell(Text(orderItem.title)),
        DataCell(Text(orderItem.price.toString())),
      ]),
      DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell('Total: ${orderItem.price}'),
      DataCell(""),
      DataCell(""),

      ]),
    ],
 )
```